# Error in return value of a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the JavaScript (Set array elements) exercise that I'm trying to solve :

Write a function setFirstElement that takes an array and an arbitrary variable. The variable should be inserted as the first element in the array. The array should be returned. setFirstElement([1, 2], 3) should return [3, 2].

This is my code :

```
   function setFirstElement(a,b){
   var result=[b,a[1]];
   return result;
   }
```

This is the error I get :

> setFirstElement([ ], 1) does not return [ 1 ], but [ 1, undefined ].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the index zero to value of parameter b.

```js
function setFirstElement(a,b){
    a[0] = b;
    return a;
}

var res = setFirstElement([1, 2], 3);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to access **2nd element from an empty** array i.e `a[1]` which is `undefined`. You can make this way to handle your existing code.

```js
function setFirstElement(a, b) {
  var result;
  if(a && !a.length == 0){
    result = [b, a[1]];
  }else{
    result = [b];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(setFirstElement([], 1));
console.log(setFirstElement([1,2], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns [1, undefined] because the second element in array a is undefined. 
Javascript arrays don't work like that. I suggest you using if statement that checks whether array a is shorter then 1.

```
function setFirstElement(a,b) {
    if (a.length < 2) {
        return [b];
    } else {
        return [b,a[1]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite confused.

First, if you add to an array another array you'll end up with [1, [3]].
Then don't forget that arrays starts from 0, so 1 is the second element.
Third, as pointed out, you need to check if the array is empty on the first round.

Here's a working example:

```js
function setFirstElement(array, el) {
  if (array.length > 0) {
    array.shift();
    return [el, ...array];
  } else {
    return [el];
  }
}

console.log(setFirstElement([], 1));
console.log(setFirstElement([2, 3, 4], 1));
console.log(setFirstElement(['b', 'c'], 'a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do this than constructing a new array.

The instructions say

> The variable should be inserted as the first element in the array. The array should be returned.

That makes it sound more like you should be modifying the array argument than creating a new array, which is easier. Like this:

```js
function setFirstElement(a, b) {
  a[0] = b;
  return a;
}

var x = setFirstElement([1, 2], 3);
console.log(x);

var y = setFirstElement([], 1);
console.log(y);
```